# Is there a way to Postpone call to RecyclerView.onBindViewHolder?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

There is a horizontal recyclerView that only shows pictures that are loaded by Picasso in the `onBindViewHolder` method. I had put a log inside the method and found out it is called x times (x is the size of my array e.g. 8). Is it possible to tell the recyclerView to actually wait for the user to scroll, then call more onBindViewHolder? Say we have 8 images and only two of them are shown at the initial load, but since the onBindViewHolder is called for all of the elements in the array, Picasso already loaded all the images.

Comment: Have you tried [`RecyclerView#setItemViewCacheSize(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView#setItemViewCacheSize(int))?

Comment: Why would you want to postpone something that is actually good for user experience. If images are loaded only when the user sees them then the user will have to wait, interrupting them. The Recycler is optimized for loading only the ammount of items that the device can handle, if you increase your arrat to several hundreds you will see how onBindViewHolder wont happen in a1 to 1 relation

Comment: Bind should be called for visible views only by default. If you're experiencing it creating and binding your entire dataset instantly,  You have a layout issue which allows `RecyclerView` to have unconstrained width.

Comment: @TheWanderer No change! (wondering why)

Comment: @Pawel yep, this is inside a relative layout: 
```<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/screenshots_recview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/changes"
                    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                    android:scrollbars="none" />```